# Расстояние от точки (A) до плоскости, определенной нормалью (PNormal) и точкой (P) лежащей на этой плоскости

Tags: геометрия, коллизии

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как найти расстояние от точки (A) до плоскости, определенной вектором нормали (NormalVector) и точкой (P) лежащей на этой плоскости?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь канонической формулой расстояния до плоскости:

[image: A(x - x0) + B(y - y0) + C(z - z0) = d]

В ней есть всё, что вам нужно:

1. Нормаль *N* = (*A*; *B*; *C*);
2. Точка *P* = (*x₀*; *y₀*; *z₀*) в плоскости;
3. Точка *A* = (*x*; *y*; *z*), до которой надо найти расстояние;
4. Собственно, расстояние *d*.

Два важных момента:

1. Если нормаль не нормирована (то есть *A² + B² + C² ≠ 1*), то вам потребуется разделить вычисленное расстояние *d* на *sqrt(A² + B² + C²)*;
2. Расстояние *d* — знаковое. Причём знак обозначает, по какую сторону от плоскости находится точка (больше нуля — по ту сторону, куда смотрит нормаль). Если же вам необходимо просто расстояние, возьмите модуль от *d*.

Comment: Я исправил название формулы, вы не против?

Comment: @VladD, всецело за.

Answer (score 3):

Ещё один подход такой. Ваше искомое расстояние — проекция вектора AP на нормаль. Длина проекции вектора на (единичный) вектор рассчитывается как скалярное произведение. Итого:

```
|(P - A) ⋅ NormalVector|
```

Если вам нужно ориентированное расстояние (положительное с одной стороны и отрицательное с другой), уберите модуль.

`NormalVector` должен быть, понятно, единичный.

Comment: А разве уравнение плоскости не является той же проекцией на нормаль, только развёрнутой до простейших арифметических операций?

Comment: @Arhad: Да, по сути это одно и то же, два разных взгляда на одну и ту же операцию.

Comment: @Arhad: По сути, уравнение плоскости есть просто `(X - P) ⋅ normal == 0`. То есть, «вектор XP лежит в плоскости».